# Unable to create cloudkit Container

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I am creating an app with core data that is hosted in a cloud kit. I have added a developer account to my Xcode. This account is added as a developer in a paid developer account (organization's account). But when I tried to create a cloudkit container it showed an error. How can I create the cloud kit container? I am following this article to create the app. [Article link](https://medium.com/apple-developer-academy-federico-ii/syncing-data-on-ios-devices-with-coredata-and-cloudkit-bed296fc26e0). What I am missing now. If it is not possible to create automatically how to create the cloudkit container manually add the capabilities and download the profile. Usually, these things(manual generation) are done by the CI/CD team. Is it possible to create it manually?[image: error screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

You can create manually, follow these steps:

1. Login to [developer](https://developer.apple.com/account).
2. Select `Identifiers` on Certificates, IDs & Profiles section.
3. Register a new identifier, and tick on `iCloud Containers`. Then paste on Project -> Capability -> iCloud.
4. Login to [CloudKit Console](https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard/home).
5. Select `CloudKit Database`.

Now you're ready to create some mock records.

Comment: by using that provisioning profile I can run the project, right?

Comment: By adding iCloud capability to bundle ID then, yes, you can.